# drbd data: failed to create debugfs dentry

Tags: drbd

CentOS 7 kernel release 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
drbd 9.0.16-1

Have one resource configured. drbd servicve is not enabled to start at boot time. I reboot the two nodes. One the first node I run `systemctl start drbd` and get

> "DRBD's startup script waits for the peer node(s) to appear.

On second now when I run `systemctl start drbd` I get:

> drbd data: failed to create debugfs dentry

## EDIT

When I run `drbdadm up resource_name` on both nodes with drbd service disable and not started I get the two nodes in Secondary/UpToDate state which is good.

## EDIT2

global_common.conf
[image]

data.res

[image]

All resource are started on otrs1. It has the `Primary` role bot shows `connecting` for the remote node, and on the remote node I don't see the other node at all.

[image]

When I run `pcs cluster stop --all` and next run `drbdadm up data` on both nodes all looks good.

[image]

Now when I mount `/dev/drbd1 /opt/otrs` on one of the nodes it gets auto promoted to the primary role.

[image]

Now when I umount and bring the reource down on both nodes and re-run `drbdadm status` I get obviously `No currently configured DRBD found.`

Now, exactly the  same happens when I run `systemctl start drbd` on both. On first node the output appears to hand but I guess it waits for the other node to start its services as well, right ?
[image]

After a reboot, the cluster and resources start on node 1 but after putting it into `standby` mode, resources are not moved:

[image]

And here's what I see `journalctl -xe`

[image]

## EDIT3

ok that's odd

[image]

I was loading the drbd kernel module at boot via `/etc/modules-load.d/drbd.conf` on both nodes but disabled it. Rebooted and to my suprise on one node it's loaded but without `drbd_transport_tcp`, is pacemaker loading the drbd kernel_module? I can't imagine that.

[image]

Now when I `systemctl disable pcsd; systemctl disable pacemaker; systemctl disable corosync` on both node and reboot an do `lsmod | grep drbd` it returns no results. I don't get it :(

Comment: Can you share your DRBD configuration with us? Also, what version of `kmod-drbd` to you have installed?

Comment: @MattKereczman Thank you for looking into my issue! Please see the EDIT section of my post. Thank you! PS. `kmod-drbd` version is on both `kmod-drbd90-9.0.16-1.el7_6.elrepo.x86_64`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Pacemaker, which you are, then you should **disable** DRBD in systemd, allowing Pacemaker to have full control of starting/stopping DRBD.

```
# systemctl disable drbd
```

DRBD *should* load it's transport modules when it brings up it's connections, and `drbdadm up <res>` *should* load the DRBD kernel module if it isn't already loaded.

Comment: Thank you Matt but drbd service was not running and disable on both nodes from starting during boot. What I did, I've added `auto-promote no` in the `global_common.conf` on both nodes. I also discovered that there was a spli brain condition reported `journalctl | grep split`. What I did next, stopped the corosync service on both nodes and followed https://docs.linbit.com/docs/users-guide-9.0/#s-resolve-split-brain . Was it the correct way to resolve a split brain condition ?

Comment: That is the correct way to resolve a split brain. Do you happen to have anything being "denied" in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`?

Comment: Yes, but I think this was related to `selinux` being enabled on node2.